# Waiting for a function to complete before updating variables

Tags: c

I'm still a beginner in programming. I was writing some code (C on Linux) to calculate the page rank of some example webpages. I'm using the google formula, which is here: [http link](http://www.pagerank.dk/Pagerank-formula/Introduction.htm)

Here is the code I wrote:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

double iResA, iResB, iResC, iResD, resA, resB, resC, resD;
int outLinksA = 2, outLinksB = 1, outLinksC = 2;

int main(){
    // get initial results for all PR
    iResA = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((0.33/outLinksB) + (0.33/outLinksC)));
    iResB = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((0.33/outLinksA) + (0.33/outLinksC)));
    iResC = 0.05 + (0.85 * (0.33/outLinksA));

    printf("initial values for all PR:\nA: %.8lf\nB: %.8lf\nC: %.8lf\n\n", iResA, iResB, iResC);
    
    resA = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((iResB/outLinksB) + (iResC/outLinksC)));
    resB = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((iResA/outLinksA) + (iResC/outLinksC)));
    resC = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((iResA/outLinksA)));

    printf("new values for all PR:\nA: %.8lf\nB: %.8lf\nC: %.8lf\n\n", resA, resB, resC);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        resA = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((resB/outLinksB) + (resC/outLinksC)));
        resB = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((resA/outLinksA) + (resC/outLinksC)));
        resC = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((resA/outLinksA)));
        printf("Iteration: %d\nnew values for all PR:\nA: %.8lf\nB: %.8lf\nC: %.8lf\n\n", i + 1, resA, resB, resC);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have to find initial results to work with, I have set the damping factor (d) to 0.05 (`(1-0.85)/3` was used to calculate that, I'm dividing by 3 because that's how many imaginary web pages I'm working with).

The problem is that I will have to create a new variable for every iteration, so this means whatever's inside the "for" loop is technically wrong. `resA` will be given a new value with each iteration, and that new value will be used to calculate `resB`, which is not good. I want to be able to use the old value of `resA` to calculate `resB`, when the iteration is finished, only then do I want the new value to be used, and that value must remain constant until the next iteration.

Perhaps there is a much easier method, and I am just over-complicating things. I'm sorry if this is really easy and I'm just not seeing a way to create a good implementation. What new things must I learn to make my life easier trying to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Allocate new variables
2. Store the result to the new variables during calculation
3. Store results to the original variables from the new variables after calculation

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       double new_resA = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((resB/outLinksB) + (resC/outLinksC)));
       double new_resB = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((resA/outLinksA) + (resC/outLinksC)));
       double new_resC = 0.05 + (0.85 * ((resA/outLinksA)));
       resA = new_resA;
       resB = new_resB;
       resC = new_resC;
       printf("Iteration: %d\nnew values for all PR:\nA: %.8lf\nB: %.8lf\nC: %.8lf\n\n", i + 1, resA, resB, resC);
   }
   ```

Comment: May help OP see the logic with `/* do stuff here */` before the `resA = new_resA;` assignment. (if I follow the question correctly)

Comment: I'm able to understand this code really well. This is way way way simpler that I thought. Thank you for this!